# how to use topics in viusalforce page

Tags: visualforce, topics

Can anyone tell me how to use topics in visualforce page?
My scenario :
        I have created 15 contacts . 10 contacts are associated with topic name **test1** and 5 contacts are associated with topic name **test2**...
I wanna display the contacts associated with **test1** topic in viusalforce page

Answer (score 2):

You can use Standard List view to filter your records by topic .Here is a blog that tells how to achieve the same

http://rakeshistom.wordpress.com/2014/01/30/using-topics-to-organize-records/

> If you need same in visualforce you can use this list views in visualforce using the tag apex:listviews

https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_listViews.htm